# IEnumerable<T> Intersect with comparer in generic method

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I am creating a `LazySave<T>` in my base data access layer (`BaseDAL`) for an object database.

```
public void LazySave<T>(IEnumerable<T> TList, Func<T, T, bool> condition, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) where T : class
{
  //Select where GetOne<T> returns null, meaning this item doesn't exist
  var itemsToStore = TList.Where(TItem => GetOne<T>(e => condition(TItem, e)) == null);
  //Select where GetOne<T> returns not null, meaning this item exists
  var itemsToUpdate = TList.Where(TItem => GetOne<T>(e => condition(TItem, e)) != null);
  //Get all of the items
  var allItems = GetMany<T>();
  //Any items which aren't in TList but are in the original list need to be deleted
  var itemsToDelete = TList.Intersect(allItems, comparer);
  itemsToStore.ToList().ForEach(i => Store<T>(i));
  itemsToUpdate.ToList().ForEach(i => Update<T>(i, condition));
  itemsToDelete.ToList().ForEach(i => Delete<T>(i, condition));
}
```

I am passing the following object and comparer to the method.

```
public class BankHoliday : IBankHoliday, IEquatable<BankHoliday>
{
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  public bool Equals(BankHoliday other)
  {
    return other.Date == Date;
  }
}

public class BankHolidayComparer : IEqualityComparer<BankHoliday>
{
  public bool Equals(BankHoliday x, BankHoliday y)
  {
    return x.Date == y.Date;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(BankHoliday obj)
  {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return 0;
    return obj.Date.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Called as:

```
var comparer = (IEqualityComparer<BankHoliday>)new BankHolidayComparer();
bhDAL.LazySave<BankHoliday>(holidays, ((T, T2) => T.Date == T2.Date), comparer);
```

The list in the database has 11 dates. I delete one and then call `LazySave`, passing 10 items into `TList` however the `Intersect` returns no results and doesn't even hit `Equals` or `GetHashCode`. Any ideas> I think it is to do with my comparer...

Comment: Have you tried stepping through LazySave() with a debugger?

Comment: Where are you initializing `comparer`? I'm missing the `var comparer = new BankHolidayComparer();`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry - I just edited that as you were typing the comment probably.

Comment: @itsme86 When I said "Doesn't event hit `Equals` or `GetHashCode`" I mean that it doesn't hit break points in debug :) but yeah I have stepped through each line of code in that method

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood the purpose of `Intersect`, based on your comment:

```
//Any items which aren't in TList but are in the original list need to be deleted
var itemsToDelete = TList.Intersect(allItems, comparer);
```

`Intersect` finds the items which *are* in both sequences. I suspect you want `Except`, based on your comment:

```
var itemsToDelete = allItems.Except(TList, comparer);
```

If your custom `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method aren't being called when using `Intersect`, that would suggest that *either* `allItems` *or* `TList` (which is an odd parameter name, by the way) is empty.

Comment: `Enumeration yielded no results` with `Except` too unfortunatly

Comment: @LukeHennerley: Well what are the counts of `allItems` and `TList`? Are you sure that `allItems` really *has* any items?

Comment: The naming convention is a bit weird at second reading :P `allItems` has 11 and `TList` has 10 `BankHoliday` items

Comment: @LukeHennerley: In that case I'd expect your break-points to be hit just fine, although you really do want `Except` rather than `Intersect`. I suggest you extract this into a short but complete program (which doesn't need to get the database involved) and try to diagnose it that way, editing the code into your question.

Comment: Could having a `DAL` project with everything except for the call to the `BankHolidayDAL` affect anything?

Comment: @LukeHennerley: You shouldn't need much at all - just construct a couple of lists explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe IEqualityComparer is intended for an external class that is used to compare instances of an object?

On the BankHoliday class, try implementing IEquatable with overrides:

`public override bool Equals(object obj)`

and

`public override int GetHashCode()`

**EDIT**: and use @Jon's Except code example.

Comment: Sorry I had old code on my clipboard, I implement `IEquatable` already in `BankHoliday`, i'll edit the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question, but just to confirm - you are putting your break points on the comparer's Equals and GetHashCode? (Not the BankHoliday's methods)

Also the line below will have to be called before the break points will be hit, because of lazy evaluation of the intersect.

```
itemsToDelete.ToList().ForEach(i => Delete<T>(i, condition));
```